# ReportViewer Erro genérico GDI+

Tags: c#

No ReportViewer, alguns pedidos gerados estão gerando exceção, e quando isso ocorre, não consigo nem exportar para PDF, mas para DOC funciona. Alguém sabe o que está acontecendo?

Utilizo C# com VS2010 e .Net 4.5

Descrição da *exception*:

```
em System.Drawing.Imaging.Metafile..ctor(Stream stream)
em Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.MetaFilePage..ctor(Stream metaFileStream, PageSettings pageSettings)
em Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportPrintDocument.OnPrintPage(PrintPageEventArgs e)
em System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument._OnPrintPage(PrintPageEventArgs e)
em System.Drawing.Printing.PrintController.PrintLoop(PrintDocument document)
em System.Drawing.Printing.PrintController.Print(PrintDocument document)
em System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument.Print()
em Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportViewer.PrintDialog(PrinterSettings printerSettings)
```

Comment: Olá. Poderia acrescentar à pergunta o bocado de código que julga estar a gerar a excepção?

Comment: Poderia sim, mas acredito que não vai adiantar, pois somente gera a exceção quando executo o PrintDialog() no reporviewer. Uma informação importante que esqueci de mencionar é que só acontece isso quando vou imprimir ou exportar para PDF, ou seja, ele renderiza corretamente, visualiza os dados na tela, exporta para .DOC, mas imprimir e gerar PDF não funciona.

Comment: Se o ReporterViewer está recebendo as informações e exibindo, faça o teste com sua aplicação em outro computador ou em uma maquina virtual, uso o RV a bastante tempo e não tive este problema, más uma coisa que deve atentar-se é as dimensões da pagina, rodapé e etc no projeto, na web você pode encontrar padrões.

Comment: entrei no site para postar uma dúvida e vi que esta ainda estava sem solução, mas eu encontrei o problema. O caso é que eu utilizava na classe um atributo do tipo uint, e no RV, quando ia imprimir ou gerar PDF, dava erro, foi só trocar para int e o problema foi resolvido.